# mouse periodically stops and keyboard also sometimes doesn't register clicks

Tags: keyboard, mouse-pointer

i am using an old dell 790 with 8 gb of ram 160 gig hdd and an i5 2400 i am using ubuntu wayland  22.04.1 LTS the cpu utilization is very low so it isn't that i am using an old razer keyboard that works fine on my other pc ram is also low utilization so i don't expect it is that. Any help would be apreciated

Comment: Is it a wireless mouse?

Comment: Quad core CPU with 8 GB memory computer is relatively new and no problem. The USB 1&2 port provides max 2.5W (5V-0.5A). Razer RGB and some high power consumption mouse exceed the limitation. Can you try them plugin to front and back USB port and see what happens.